# Cómo incluir la configuración de VisualStudio en un proyecto

Tags: configuración

Cómo incluir la configuración de VisualStudio en un proyecto, de forma que cuando abra el proyecto se importe dicha configuración del proyecto?
Cuando refiero a configuraciónd el proyecto habl de la que se puede importar o exportar en Tools>Import and Export Settings.

Comment: Podrias usar https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyVeselov.SettingsGuard  , revisalo